# Bootstrap 4 text "go out" from the table on phone resolution

Tags: html, css, html-table, bootstrap-4

I have a problem with bootstrap table, on phone resolution, my table in phone resolution will appear like this:

[image: Table]

Here is my code:

```
<table class="table table-hover table-dark mt-3 table-bordered">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="col" >#</th>
                                    <th scope="col" >Value</th>
                                    <th scope="col" >Action</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="row">Username</th>
                                    <td><?=$Username?></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="row">Email</th>
                                    <td><?=$Email?></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                </tr>
                               </tbody>
                             </table>
```

If you look the text of the photo you will see that the text "go out" from the screen, how can I fix it?

Comment: Use media querys to reduce the size of text and reduce margins and paddings in mobile resolutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add **table-responsive** class to the table. You can also make is specific to view breakpoints.

More details [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/tables/#responsive-tables)